# Magnific Popup - Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe

Tags: magnific-popup

Magnific pop up for Google Maps not working on Chrome mobile. When triggered I get "Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe".

It works perfectly with the Google Maps URL given in the Magnific example but not when I use my own, I'm not sure if Google have changed their URL structure since but it looks like the new "embeded" URL is causing the problem.

Here's an example of the kind of URL I'm using: https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2382.9841570555454!2d-6.227123684388949!3d53.32563697997466!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48670ec57aa7b09d%3A0x7965235d57af13f!2sClayton+Hotel+Ballsbridge!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sie!4v1453039698107

Is there a way I can change this URL to more like the working URL structure given in the example?: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=221B+Baker+Street,+London,+United+Kingdom&hl=en&t=v&hnear=221B+Baker+St,+London+NW1+6XE,+United+Kingdom

Been wracking my brains with this one....any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this too. It's because Magnific Popup uses "maps.google." whereas Google now uses "www.google.". I had this which didn't work

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Leathermarket+Gardens

and I changed it to

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Leathermarket+Gardens

Which now works.

Hope that helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps should be embedded in iframe in Magnific pop plugin

Sample:

```
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=221B+Baker+Street,+London,+United+Kingdom&amp;hl=en&amp;t=v&amp;hnear=221B+Baker+St,+London+NW1+6XE,+United+Kingdom" data-lightbox="iframe">View map</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the right solution isn't listed here. The only thing you have to do is removing this attribute: `disableOn: 700`.

Keep only the code below:

```
$('.popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,
    fixedContentPos: false
});
```

Then it will works again.

PS: If you want to keep the new Google URL address form, you should change code inside `jquery.magnific-popup.js` library from:

```
     gmaps: {
                index: '//maps.google.',
                src: '%id%&output=embed'
            }
```

to:

```
     gmaps: {
                index: 'google.com/maps/',
                src: '%id%'
            }
```